# com.android.camera.action.CROP in objective-c?

Tags: android, objective-c, crop

I've been created an app on android and I'm using the com.android.camera.action.CROP intent to crop picture (the user can select the crop area).
I'm searching an easy way to do the same with objective-c as android could. I found some solution but it's only to crop with fixed parameter.

Do you have idea (github link, blog link...)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use the third party libraries than here are the link,

[pecropViewController](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/PEPhotoCropEditor)

[RSKImageCropper](https://github.com/ruslanskorb/RSKImageCropper)

or if you want to use inbuilt cropper of ios than when you create imagepicker controller object set it's property like this

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType =   UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

here `picker.allowsEditing` is the property which allow to crop image in square.

Hope, this will help you

Answer (score 0):

There are so many good example available for crop image with Objective-C.

Please check few examples list as below.

1. [PEPhotoCropEditor](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/PEPhotoCropEditor)
2. [TOCropViewController](https://github.com/TimOliver/TOCropViewController)
3. [BABCropperView](https://github.com/brynbodayle/BABCropperView)
4. [PhotoTweaks](https://github.com/itouch2/PhotoTweaks)
5. [MDImageCroper](https://github.com/mohammedDehairy/MDImageCroper)
6. [InstagramPhotoPicker](https://github.com/wenzhaot/InstagramPhotoPicker)
7. [RSKImageCropper](https://github.com/ruslanskorb/RSKImageCropper)
8. [CropperView](https://github.com/tiny2n/CropperView)
9. [VPImageCropper](https://github.com/windshg/VPImageCropper)
10. [PerfectImageCropper](https://github.com/goldhuang/PerfectImageCropper)